# Assigning column names in a data file read by R

Tags: r, data-mining, data-science

I am trying to read a network data (graph of ids) in R. The file is named 'network.txt' and data is as follows:

```
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
4029 1
4030 1
4031 1
4032 1
4033 1
19088 9040
19089 9040
19090 9040
19091 9040
19092 9040
19093 9040
19094 9040
19095 9040
19096 9040
19097 9040
```

And, I am reading it using read.table() module.

```
data = read.table("network.txt",sep="\t",header=FALSE)
colnames( data ) <- unlist(c('to', 'from'))

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("to", "from")) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

So, how to assign column names? Is there any mistake reading the original data file ?

Comment: Given the error, I suspect your data is not read in correctly. Check `str(data)`. Most likely you just need to take out the `sep` parameter, and it will work.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I would read the question and answer before dupe tagging.  I think the linked post nowhere addresses the issue in the question unless you found it somewhere hidden in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need

```
colnames( data ) <- c('to', 'from')
```

as `c('to', 'from')` returns a `vector` and `unlist` does nothing here.  The `unlist` is used in cases where the output is `list` or (`data.frame` which is also a `list` with elements of equal `length` aka `columns`)

---

Regarding the error, it is possible that we used the wrong `sep` resulting in a single column which can be identified by checking the `str(data)`.  I would use `sep=""`

---

In addition to the above recommendation, we can specify the `col.names` in `read.table`

```
data <- read.table("network.txt",sep="",header=FALSE, col.names = c("to", "from"))
```

Or use `fread` from `data.table` (which picks up the delimiter automatically)

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("network.txt", header=FALSE, col.names = c("to", "from"))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I am a beginner in R. And, I thought playing with real data is a good idea to start with it. It works very well now.

Answer (score 5):

You can either provide the column names within the `read.table` function call, as such:

`read.table("network.txt", col.names = c("Col1", "Col2"))`

Or, you can also do it in a similar fashion to your attempt with the `names` function:

```
test1 <- read.table("Question1.txt")
names(test1) <- c("col1", "col2")
```